# How do I make an ISO from a disc?

Tags: iso, burning

I have a disc here, and I need to take an ISO image of the disc. Is there a piece of software I can use to get the image from the disc, or does Ubuntu ship with one?

Answer (score 12):

While Brasero is probably easier, if you're interested, here's how to create an iso from the command line using mkisofs:

```
genisoimage -r -J -o cd_image.iso /directory
```

The -r and -J tags allow for long filenames. -o stands for output, followed by the output file and directory. Afterwards, you can mount the image using mount, or burn with wodim.

The [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning) for Ubuntu is a fantastic resource. Take a look at the link for more details.

Answer (score 10):

Use Brasero Disc Burner:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or via the terminal, run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install brasero
```

---

To copy a disc to an ISO image, click on `Disc copy`, then choose `Image File` as the destination.

Answer (score 10):

Graphical apps such ad `Brasero` or `K3b` should work fine for creating an iso from a disk, but there are actually several ways of doing it. I have always used the slightly more complicated, but for my old hardware, more reliable, way that uses `dd/if`. If you are confident doing it this way (or old fashioned), it has always worked for me:

- First place the disk in your drive and get the block and volume size with

  ```
  isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr1
  ```

or whatever the `/dev` node is for your target drive.

- Next run the following, replacing the `/dev` node with your own and place the block and volume numbers gained from `isoinfo` where `<isoinfo result>` occurs below:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/sr1 bs=<isoinfo result> count=<isoinfo result> of=/home/mike/Folder/thegreat.iso
  ```

  (Some example values reported by `isoinfo` for a physical disk are: `"Logical block size is: 2048, Volume size is: 309669"`. So, in the `dd/if` commands above, bs would be 2048 and count would be 309669. Do not use these values, however, use the ones `isoinfo` gives for your own disk.)

  Also make sure you use the correct `/dev` node of your cd/dvd drive, eg. usually `/dev/sr0`, `/dev/sr1`.

Even though most people use graphical apps, I found that the `dd/if` method worked more reliably than `brasero` for me.

---

I have prepared a script for making an iso from a disc.

As I use positional parameters in the script, you must specify the device (`$1`) and the iso to be created (`$2`),

As an example, if it is not in your `~/bin`, you could call it with:

```
./script_name.sh /dev/sr0 /home/$USER/new.iso
```

The contents of the script; make it executable with `chmod u+x` after creating it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 and $2 are specified on the command line when the script is called; $1 must be /dev/sr0 or whatever is the drive; $2 is the location and name of iso to be created

val1="$(isoinfo -d -i "$1" | grep -i "block size" | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}')"
val2="$(isoinfo -d -i "$1" | grep -i "volume size" | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}')"

dd if="$1" bs="$val1" count="$val2" of="$2"

exit 0
```

Comment: `isoinfo` will only report on iso9660 images.  It will ignore any other data (like the HFS section of a hybrid ISO/HFS CD).  Those types are pretty rare now, but do pop up occasionally.

Comment: @charlesbridge Useful to note it here and good to make people aware of it, but hybrid cds are, as you say, pretty unusual these days.

Comment: You may want to add that `isoinfo` is contained in package `genisoimage`.

Answer (score 3):

Default burner app in ubuntu `Brasero` can do that. It is shipped with ubuntu.

Choose `Copy CD/DVD` option. In properties you choose the type (.iso)

Answer (score 0):

I always liked using `dvdisaster`, as it gracefully handles bad (scratched) CDs.

It was actually written to recover data from bad CDs, but it nicely works with good readable CDs too.

Comment: This is not a recovery question, it is "how to make an ISO from a disk", not "how to recover a disk using ISO's"

Comment: @StarOS: `dvdisaster` has a nice UI for reading existing disks too.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use the GUI and without having to install anything is:

gnome-disks --> Select CD/DVD drive --> Partition options --> Create partition image